# How to link to chrome extension like Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store

I'd like to self host a chrome extension on my own site but would like the install experience to be the same as on the chrome web store. Specifically, I'd like to have a "add to chrome" button which asks the user to install the extension with one more click. Currently on self hosted extensions you have to confirm the download and then confirm the install.

Here's an example of the web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/olnconaknblgbkfgknkfmmfhhbebkekd

The only reason I'd like to self host is so that they can stay on my site while installing the extension.

I'd be perfectly fine hosting on the chrome webstore as well if that helped with the experience (i.e. a special link from my site to the chrome webstore that would start the download immediately).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chrome webstore has special treatment, you can't reproduce it.

To save you trouble of self hosting, you can provide a direct link to crx file hosted on webstore which has the following format:

```
http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<EXTENSION_ID_HERE>%26uc%26lang%3Den-US&prod=chrome
```

Users would still need to confirm 2 times, but at least you don't have to host it and users won't leave your site.

**UPDATE**

Chrome 15, that was just released into stable branch, has [Inline Installation](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html), which seems like exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: What about embedding some sort of iFrame of the webstore on my own site?

Comment: for also downloading extensions you can use http://chrome-extension-downloader.com

Comment: It is worth mentioning, you can no longer link directly to the .crx file, chrome will block it.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome now has inline install that enables a one-click install on your site but downloading from the store.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Add something like this to your meta-data

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/you-chrome-id">
```

Add this any where:

```
onclick="javascript:chrome.webstore.install()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome no longer supports in-line installation of extensions.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq

> When your site calls `chrome.webstore.install()`, Chrome will no longer trigger a dialog immediately but will instead open a new foreground tab to the details page of the Chrome WebStore