# How to install extension directly without visiting chrome store

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myextenstion/lkdklkkflkfedlbfpl

like this.

i created a menu item on my website like

```
<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myextenstion/lkdklkkflkfedlbfpl  ">Click here to Download Extesnion</a>
```

which is working fine'

Now i want user just click and extension popup appear directly .

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to link to chrome extension like Chrome Web Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936277/how-to-link-to-chrome-extension-like-chrome-web-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Chrome 33 on windows, you could self-host your crx file and serve it with a given content-type to trigger the installation popup.

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting

Since them, to avoid malware, users can only install extensions hosted on the chrome web store (if they don't use the "developer mode" settings in chrome).

To install from a third party website directly, chrome provides a javascript API (called inline installation).

Here is the documentation

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation